# Windows SSL Certificates Store and Python LDAP

Tags: python, windows, ssl, ldap, python-ldap

I use Odoo to integrate with Windows Active Directory through `python-ldap` library. We have an internal organization certificate that should be installed on the system supposed to connect to the AD server. I don't control the certificates through `ldap.set_option` methods, and I don't want to override this part of the code (part of Odoo upstream code).

In Linux, just adding the CA certificates into `ca-certificates` directories makes everything work without issues.

Under Windows, adding the CA certificates to Windows Certificates Store doesn't reflect on `python-ldap` and gives me the error:

```
CONNECT_ERROR: {'info': 'error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed (unable to get
 local issuer certificate)', 'desc': 'Connect error'}
```

The code that generates the error is as following:

```py
import ldap
uri = 'ldap://<server>:<port>'
conn = ldap.initialize(uri)
conn.start_tls_s()
```

I tried also looking for configuration files that `libldap` parses to override the CA certificates directory, but I couldn't find the respective Windows configuration file path to `/etc/openldap/ldap.conf`.

Software Versions:

- Python: 2.7 (inside a virtualenv)
- Python-LDAP: 2.5.2
- Shell: Git Bash 4.4.23(1)-release (x86_64-pc-msys) / Command Prompt
- Windows: 10
- Odoo: 10.0

Answer (score 0):

I finally discovered the Windows path to configure OpenLDAP using the [documentation here](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/libldap-2.4-2/ldap.conf.5.en.html); the paths that worked with me:

- `~/ldaprc` = `C:\Users\<username>\ldaprc` (works under Git Bash only)
- `./ldaprc` = `<current working directory>\ldaprc` (works under Git Bash and Command Prompt)

Comment: Hi Anass, Can you please provide some more information on this. Do you have some sample config availbale for odoo?